# Comparación entre campo DATE y campo DATETIME con condicionantes CASE tiene ligeros errores en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta de SQL:

```
 SELECT e.no_empleado AS no_empleado,MIN(start_event) AS start_event,end_event, 
           CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entrada) SECOND, start_event) > 15
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entrada) SECOND, start_event) <= 40
                THEN 'RETARDO MENOR' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entrada) SECOND, start_event) > 40
                AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_FORMAT(start_event, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(entrada) SECOND, start_event) <= 90
                THEN 'RETARDO MAYOR'
                ELSE 'CHECADA' END AS title
FROM events AS e 
    JOIN empleados AS em ON e.no_empleado = em.no_empleado 
    WHERE e.no_empleado = $no_empleado AND title = 'CHECADA'
    GROUP BY no_empleado, DATE(start_event)
```

Dicha consulta la utilizo haciendo referencia a una tabla llamada "events" que contiene la columna "no_empleado" que contiene el número identificador de cada empleado, "start_event" de tipo DATETIME que contiene la fecha y hora de un registro y "title" de tipo VARCHAR que contiene el título de dicho evento/registro. En esta tabla se registran las entradas y salidas de los empleados en su lugar de trabajo.

A la vez se hace referencia a la tabla "empleados" que contiene una columna "no_empleado" con su respectivo número identificador y "entrada" de tipo TIME que contiene la hora de entrada de dicha persona.

Las reglas son simples: si el empleado tiene un registro antes de su hora de entrada y hasta 15 minutos después de la misma, se considera "CHECADA" (que contiene el campo "title" por default); si el empleado tiene un registro después de los 15 minutos de su hora de entrada y antes o igual a 40 minutos después de su hora de entrada, se considera "RETARDO MENOR"; y si el empleado tiene un registro después de 40 minutos de su hora de entrada y hasta 90 minutos después, se considera "RETARDO MAYOR".

La consulta funciona con la gran mayoría de mis registros, pero he detectado pocas excepciones donde aplica mal las condiciones. Por ejemplo, tengo un registro donde start_event es "2022-11-17 07:14:00" de tipo DATETIME y entrada es "07:00:00" de tipo TIME , por lo que debería mostrarse en la columna "title" como "CHECADA", pero en lugar de mostrarse de esa manera, se muestra como "RETARDO MAYOR". ¿Por qué sucede esto? De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Sería más fácil pillar el error si pasaras por una subconsulta que te entregara la diferencia en minutos, cosa que puedas ver qué le está llegando al `CASE`. De todos modos, podrías obtener la diferencia en minutos de un modo menos trabajoso usando `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(entrada),TIME(start_event))`